# MySQL conditional subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a subquery based on a condition:

```
SELECT `table1`.`id`, (
    SELECT `table2`.`name` 
    FROM `table2` 
    WHERE `table2`.`id` = `table1`.`table2_id`
)
```

conditional on `table2_id` not being 0.

So if it's zero, only `table1`.`id` gets selected, else `table1`.`id` and `table2`.`name` gets selectectected. Assume I'll inner join the tables later.

I tried both `CASE THEN` and `IF ()`, but I can't get the syntax to work.

I'm using MySQL 5.5

Comment: There's almost certainly a better, more straightforward way of accomplishing whatever result you're after.  SQL queries whose columns are conditional on some requirement are often a sign of bad table design, as a well-designed database schema would never require such a condition.  See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't think you can have the result schema depend on the query; the schema of the query result must be uniform for all rows. What you can do is use `CASE` to select `NULL` when `table2_id` is 0, though. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, In two queries, yes. But I'm in Node and chaining queries one after another gets out of hand quickly. I'm hoping there is a pure SQL solution. I welcome suggestions, thought. @Patrick87, not quite. I want to join tables if `table1`.`table2_id` is not 0.

Comment: The usual way is to UNION your two queries, which is a perfectly sensible approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you simply want to left join to table 2 ? This means it will show all table1.id, and if table 2 matches it will show otherwise it will be null

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.name
From table1
Left join table2
 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if the `table.table2_id` is 0, it'll return an empty set because there are no `table2.id` = 0. At least that has been my experience.

Comment: I just learnt the difference between LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN. Thank you very much!